# Message from rank 1 and tag 3 truncated;31050432 bytes received but buffer size is 30844800

Tags: mpi

I have some problem with my MPI code. This issue does not happen with two processes (cpus), but it appears when I have more than 3 ranks (cpus). I thought the tag might be the reason for this error because during the computation, but the corresponding receive have the same tag of the send.

what would be the problem? Given multiple ranks (cpus) are clashing with the same tag?

part of my code:

```
if (id != 0)
{
    MPI_Isend(liquidx[1][0], 1, new_dtype, id - 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
        &req[0]);
    MPI_Isend(liquidy[1][0], 1, new_dtype, id - 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
        &req[1]);
}
if (id != p - 1)
{
    MPI_Irecv(liquidx[memory_size - 1][0], 1, new_dtype, id + 1, 0,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[0]);
    MPI_Irecv(liquidy[memory_size - 1][0], 1, new_dtype, id + 1, 1,
        MPI_COMM_WORLD, &req[1]);
}
MPI_Waitall(2, req, status);
```

Error:

> [0] fatal error Fatal error in PMPI_Gather: Message truncated, error
>   stack: PMPI_Gather(583).......................:
>   MPI_Gather(sbuf=0x00000000084463C0, scount=150, dtype=USER,
>   rbuf=0x000000000FB9C080, rcount=150, dtype=USER, root=0,
>   MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed MPIR_Gather(210).......................:
>   MPIDI_CH3U_Post_data_receive_found(193): Message from rank 1 and tag 3
>   truncated; 31050432 bytes received but buffer size is 30844800

Comment: The error message is related to `MPI_Gather()` but your snippet is not. Please upload a [MCVE]. Note your snippet requires up to 4 requests.

Comment: MPI_Gather(liquidz[1][0], size, new_dtype, save_data[0][0], size,new_dtype, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

Comment: Here is my MPI_Gather function. Due to that fact that I want to use it at cluster, so I did not use the function like if id==1;if id==2;if id ==3....But with the tag specified (0,1), various cpus will clash? The buffer of MPI_Irev() is not the same.Thanks. Looking forward to receive your comments.

Comment: A [MCVE] is required if you need any help. Also include your MPI library vendor and version.

Comment: I was wrong about the buffers. `MPI_Gather()` is a collective operation and must hence be invoked by **all** the ranks of the communicator.

Comment: How can I contact with you directly, I will try to min my code. Can you share me your email? thanks a lot  if  it is possiable

Comment: Simply edit your question, insert your code and format it.